# Tkinter widget creation using Python3 of Rasberry Pi. Create an array of checkbuttons

Tags: python, arrays, checkbox, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I wish to create an array of checkboxes and reference them as an array of some sort.
This makes writing the code a lot easier with shorter blocks.
The ideal situation would be something like this

```
for IOBit in range(8)
    self.GPIO_Array[IOBit] = tk.BooleanVar()
    tk.Checkbutton(self.MyFrame , variable = self.GPIO_Array[IOBit] )
```

Afterwards I would have an array of 8 *boolean* variables called `GPIO_Array[]`.
I would then want to use access these such as

```
self.GPIO_Array[Index].get()
```

Any thoughts of how to go about this is perhaps a different approach that allows loops rather than a large block of semi repeated code?

Comment: What is the question? What's stopping you from doing exactly what you suggest?

Comment: The problem is the variable which always takes on a value for IOBit of 7 for all the buttons pressed which is not what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't show actual code, only "something like" your actual code, it's hard to say for certain what you're doing wrong. Here's a working example where I've tried to mimic what you want:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.MyFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.MyFrame.pack(side="top", fill="x")

        self.GPIO_Array = []
        for IOBit in range(8):
            self.GPIO_Array.append(tk.IntVar())
            w = tk.Checkbutton(self.MyFrame, variable=self.GPIO_Array[IOBit],
                               onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=self.show)
            w.pack(side="left")

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="", width=8)
        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="x")

        # show the current value when the GUI first starts
        self.show()

    def show(self):
        s = ""
        for IOBit in range(8):
            s += str(self.GPIO_Array[IOBit].get())
        self.label.configure(text=s)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Example(root)
    app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```